# NET START <SERVICE> - how/where to get the service name?

Tags: windows, service, windows-services

I need to create a common script to restart service:

```
net stop <service>
net start <service>
```

Problem is that I don't know the name of the service. 
For example for "`printer spooler`" is the name "`spooler`".

How can I find the name for any service?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Start → Run
2. Then type: `services.msc`.
3. Double click on the service that you're interested in.

You should see:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Use [`sc`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx) rather than `net`, since it boasts a lot more features. It was first introduced (IIRC) in Windows XP:

```
sc GetKeyName "printer spooler"
```

should print something like:

```
[SC] GetServiceKeyName SUCCESS  Name = Spooler
```

And you can then use that name in other commands, like `sc start` and `sc stop`.

Comment: See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/315166/net-start-service-and-sc-start-what-is-the-difference) for differences between the two.

Answer (score 7):

I get that from the registry: HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services. Each subkey is the name of a service or driver. Just search for the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 7):

For systems that have access to PowerShell. A better way to do this is with the Cmdlet "Get-Service". You can invoke it by typing:

```
Get-Service -DisplayName "Print Spooler"
```

Which will return:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  Spooler            Print Spooler
```

Where you get the name of the service under Name. The DisplayName parameter can take wild cards if you like.
If you want to get the Display name you can write:

```
 Get-Service -Name spooler
```

Which would return the same table as above. You can also write:

```
(Get-Service -DisplayName "Print Spooler").Name
```

To get just the name (avoid a table).

This is really only necessary to do to check if a service is running. PowerShell have the Cmdlet Start-Service and Stop-Service which takes the parameter -Name and -DisplayName so you could write:

```
Start-Service -DisplayName "Print Spooler"
Stop-Service -DisplayName "Print Spooler"
```

To start and stop the service.

In this case I've used PowerShell 2.0 so I guess it will work on any Windows above and including XP.

Comment: Example of using wildcard: `Get-Service -Name *sql*` to get a list of services that have 'sql' in their name.